# JavaFX Cannot Find Image

Tags: java, image, javafx

just started a new project and am already running in to some issues. I am trying to display an image with javafx but the compiler is complaining that the provided location is invalid. Here is all of my code so far (apart from some imports):

```
public class main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Stage stage = primaryStage;
        String version = "alpha";
        stage.setTitle("Space Invaders v. " + version);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Image pic = new Image("Art\\whiteMonster.jpg");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(pic);
        vbox.getChildren().add(image);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,0,200,200);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        vbox.getChildren().add(rect);

        //Creating the scene.
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

If I change the file path to the images url where I found it in google image search it displays the black rectangle added beneath it (just to test if everything works) but not the image. In the current configuration however it simply throws an error saying the URL is either invalid or that the resource was not found. What makes me think that this should work is this example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html

Thanks for any help.

PS. I've been looking at other similar questions here but haven't found anything that helped me and if you feel like you need any other information give me a shout.

-----EDIT-----
[image: Project Structure, Code and File Manager, all images are placed directly in the "Art" folder]
Project Structure, Code and File Manager, all images are placed directly in the "Art" folder.

I hope that is all you need.

Comment: What is the location of your image with respect to your class file?

Comment: I do believe and I hope it's what I've written

Comment: I can see `Art\\whiteMonster.jpg` but it doesn't say anything where the image is placed relative to the class file. Additionally, if you can provide a snapshot of the project structure, I would help a lot.

Comment: Check the edit, thanks.

Comment: Your image should show the image and the class file. Expand the package so as to show both the image and the class file, take a snapshot and replace with the existing one.

Comment: Crap sorry, thought I did that

Comment: no that won't work. You need to copy the image inside the `src` and then try to load it using `Image pic = new Image("whiteMonster.jpg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the image inside the folder .Drag the image to the "src" and use `Image pic = new Image("whiteMonster.jpg");`. It should be displayed under the .java files but a little bit in the left.

Comment: Thanks, had to refresh the project structure as well though.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution for me was to Close Project and open the Javafx Project
> again
> [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNeDL.png)

This refreshes the images URL for Javafx.
**NOTE: I am using Intellij IDEA Java version 16 with Javafx.**

- Error was: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found`